# version control of docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker-compose

My application has 4 docker containers that talk to each other and is specified with a `docker-compose.yml` file, so I can just do `docker-compose up -d` from the location where that file is stored and it starts.

I am virtually the end of setting up my CI service to go from commit to the git repository to testing and then building the docker images that I need for my deploy.  I now need to sort out how to deploy.

I already have the current version running, and my `docker-compose.yml` file is configured via environment variables held in a `.env` file. It is unlikely that it will change between versions, but it might. What will change is the `.env` file, as that specifies image names and tags that the CI system has just build and which the `docker-compose.yml` file will use to start the new version of the running system. `.env` is created on the fly by scripts in the repository and is run by the CI system in its workspace.  My deploy step is really just about copying `.env` and `docker-compose.yml` into place and then stopping the old set of services and starting the new.

My question is, if I change the `.env` file or `docker-compose.yml` under a running version, will `docker-compose down` properly stop the old running images, so that when I immediately follow it with a `docker-compose up -d` I swap over to the new images. Is there a better way of handling this situation